# Are contributions to the American Political Science Review labeled "Letter" peer reviewed?

Tags: peer-review

I suspect that in general, they are not, but perhaps someone who knows better could clarify.

However, I am looking specifically at the *American Political Science Review*, where contributions labeled "Letter" are much longer than is typical in other journals. Are these "Letters" peer reviewed?

Comment: Ask them if you can't find it in their online materials. If the correct answer is "sometimes" then answers here might be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are peer-reviewed.

See also [their author instructions](https://www-cambridge-org.uaccess.univie.ac.at/core/journals/american-political-science-review/information/instructions-contributors):

> The American Political Science Review (APSR) publishes letters, or research notes. [...] Although **letters are reviewed like manuscripts** [*my own emphasis*], they are shorter, more focused, demonstrate a novel perspective on existing research, and encourage scholarly debate [...].